# Styling the table created by element.append() method not working

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have the table, like you see below:

[image]

Unfortunately I don't know how to style it inside the Javascript code with element.append() pethod. I tried both ways:

```
            <script>
        
            const resultsList = document.getElementById('opresults')
            const matches = document.querySelectorAll("fieldset");
            new URLSearchParams(window.location.search).forEach((value, name) => {
                resultsList.append(document.createElement('tbody'))
                resultsList.append(`${name}`)
                resultsList.append(document.createElement('td'))
                 var obj = resultsList.append(document.createElement('td'))
                obj.style.cssText = 'font-weight: bold;';
                resultList.append(obj)
                 document.body.appendChild('td');
                resultsList.append(`${value}`)
                resultsList.append(document.createElement('br'))   
            })
        </script>
```

and also:

```
             <script>
        
            const resultsList = document.getElementById('opresults')
            const matches = document.querySelectorAll("fieldset");
             const note = document.querySelector('td');

    
            new URLSearchParams(window.location.search).forEach((value, name) => {
                resultsList.append(document.createElement('tbody'))
                resultsList.append(`${name}`)
                resultsList.append(document.createElement('td'))
               
                resultsList.append(`${value}`)
                resultsList.append(document.createElement('br'))   
                css(note, {
                     'font-weight': 'bold'
                 })
            })
        </script>
```

None of them were working.
I would like to have the column "Form Question" with text emboldened.

How can I implement the CSS stylization inside the Element.append() method?

Comment: for starters you seem to append 'td' elements, outside of the 'tbody', so they're siblings and are not nested.. as for css you can either style inline ( `createElement('el').style.cssText = 'font-weight: bold'` ), but that is lazy and unnecessary. you should create a stylesheet with all you need and append it to the document head.

Comment: I have already created stylesheet, but it doesn't work within the script. This is the problem

Comment: if a stylesheet exists withing the document then you missed the correct css selectors. use classes for this that you need to add to the element and not to the 'append()' method.. i.e `let el = document.createElement('td'); el.classList.add('bold'); resultList.append(el);` .. and in you stylesheet .. `.bold { font-weight: bold }`

Comment: It doesn't work either

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make sure you have everything placed correctly as I mentioned in my comments.

ex:

```
const doc = document;
const head = doc.head;
const body = doc.body;

const stylesheet = doc.createElement('style')
stylesheet.setAttribute('rel', 'stylesheet')
head.append(stylesheet);

stylesheet.sheet.insertRule(`h4 { font-weight: 100 }`, 0);
stylesheet.sheet.insertRule(`.bold { font-weight: bold }`, 0);

let boldText = doc.createElement('h4');
boldText.innerText = 'bold';
boldText.classList.add('bold');
let normalText = doc.createElement('h4').innerText = 'normal';

body.append(boldText);
body.append(normalText);
```

Here's a fiddle..

https://jsfiddle.net/whysosergious/cy57zwxe/87/

Comment: I will accept your answer, as it works fine on your example. Unfortunately, I've dissovered, that the problem might be in other place.
See my question here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67520677/element-append-generates-unnecessary-column

Once I get the Element.append() method tidy, the javascript trigger for css styling won't be needed.

Comment: that is because your table content is not nested in the table body .. instead of `resultList.appent('tbody'); resultList.appent('td');` you need to append the 'td' element into your 'tbody' element .. `let tableBody = document.createElement('tbody'); tableBody.append(document.createElement('td').classList.add('bold')); resultList.append(tbody);` .. in that order .. like I said, you need to make sure that everything is placed/executed correctly. it will work =)