# Element.append() generates unnecessary column

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to style my table, which states an output of my HTML form.

The table was meant to include 2 columns only. I used the `Element.append()` method for pushing my HTML form data through.

My code looks as follows:

```
 <table id="opresults" class="outputtable"><p class="outputtablehead">Survey Form - output</p>
    <tr class="colname">
       <th class="question">Form question</th>
       <th class="answer">Answer</th>
    </tr>
    <tr class="opcontent">
        <script>
        
            const resultsList = document.getElementById('opresults')
            const matches = document.querySelectorAll("fieldset");
                  
            new URLSearchParams(window.location.search).forEach((value, name) => {
                resultsList.append(document.createElement('tbody'))
                resultsList.append(document.createElement('td'),`${name}:`)
                resultsList.append(document.createElement('td'))
                resultsList.append(`${value}`)
                resultsList.append(document.createElement('br'))   
               
            })
        </script> 
    </tr>
</table>
```

I don't know why my script creates an additional empty column!

I would like to have my data placed within the  operator by using the script above.
Is it possible with `Element.append()` method, or maybe should I go with `Element.insertAdjacentHTML()`

[image]

Comment: If it's a table element you can also use `Element.insertRow`

Comment: you're missing the row...

Comment: wrap your td elements inside a `tr`... and get rid of that `br`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've messed up the mark up nesting. The correct way to do it is like this (it's always good to avoid writing one liner if you don't understand the structure well)

```
<table id="opresults" class="outputtable">
  <p class="outputtablehead">Survey Form - output</p>
  <tr class="colname">
    <th class="question">Form question</th>
    <th class="answer">Answer</th>
  </tr>
  <tr class="opcontent">
    <script>
      const resultsList = document.getElementById('opresults')
      const matches = document.querySelectorAll("fieldset");
      const innerBody = document.createElement('tbody');
      resultsList.append(innerBody);

      new URLSearchParams(window.location.search).forEach((value, name) => {
        const row = document.createElement('tr');
        const tdName = document.createElement('td');
        const tdValue = document.createElement('td');

        tdName.innerText = name;
        tdValue.innerText = value;

        row.append(tdName);
        row.append(tdValue);

        innerBody.append(row);
      })

    </script>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: `<table>` elements cannot contain `<p>` elements and `<tr>` elements cannot contain `<script>` elements. The nesting is still messed up.

Comment: Yep... I agree... Only fixed the problem causing part though

Answer (score 0):

You need to add rows to your table:

```html
<table id="opresults" class="outputtable">
    <p class="outputtablehead">Survey Form - output</p>
    <tr class="colname">
       <th class="question">Form question</th>
       <th class="answer">Answer</th>
    </tr>
    <tr class="opcontent">
        <script>
            const resultsList = document.getElementById('opresults');
            const matches = document.querySelectorAll("fieldset");
            const tableBody = document.createElement('tbody');
            resultsList.appendChild(tableBody);
                  
            new URLSearchParams(window.location.search).forEach((value, name) => {
                const row = tableBody.insertRow();
                row.insertCell().innerText = `${name}:`;
                row.insertCell().innerText = value;
            });
        </script>
    </tr> 
</table>
```

This will fix your alignment problem, but I recommend you rework this markup anyways, because `<script>` inside `<tr>` elements and `<p>` elements in a `<table>` don't really belong there.

Comment: The table is empty, something must be missing.

Comment: Oh...seems like you can't insert a cell and set it's content at the same time

Comment: Updated my answer, can you try it out?

Comment: Yes, that's fine. Thank you for your effort :)